# Using if statements but value output is incorrect in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I am using the formula =IF(W2=0,0,1) but the output is 1 when the value is 0 in the cell W2.

Comment: Increase decimals in W2?

Comment: are you sure of the contents of W2.

Comment: In W2 I have divided two values but my result is 0

Comment: you probably want: `=IF(ROUND(W2,0)=0,0,1)`  You are probably running against a floating point error.

Comment: So, in future, copy W2 and paste.special value into a different cell, then you can see if you have 0 or something else. That way you can be sure of the contents of W2...

Comment: You can't divide 2 values and get 0 lol.

Comment: @findwindow  How about if the numerator is zero:  `0/5 => 0`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld sure but when does one ever do 0/5 outside of theory?

Comment: I changed up my formula to =IF(MOD(F167054/V167054,1)=0,0,1) and if I have a decimal value I want a 0 as a result. I am getting a 1 instead of the value that I want. I am dividing 5/153 and it gives me 0.03267

Comment: @findwindow What does it matter, or even mean: "outside of theory"? You made a categorical statement without confining it to certain cases.  You could certainly average numbers that sum'd to zero, and then you would have a numerator =0.

Comment: But `MOD(0.03267,1)` => `0.03267`, not zero.  If you want `0` returned if the value is decimal, then use, for your test, `INT(0.03267)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld `certainly average numbers that sum'd to zero` Are you ok?

Comment: @findwindow Your question in the comment is as off-topic as your categorical statement regarding division is incorrect. So I will not respond further.